Problem with ssd name in boot order
I decided to install Ubuntu next to Windows, but on separate ssd drives. Windows is installed by default on the SX8200PNP-512GT-S drive, and I installed Ubuntu on the second Samsung SSD 970 EVO Plus 1TB drive. Or more precisely, on one of the partitions of this drive. I'm wondering what this even means and if it's normal that in the bios, in the boot option priorities and in round brackets (), in both cases SX8200PNP-512GT-S the first of the drives. Could it be that my Ubuntu is installed incorrectly? Here's a picture of what is going on.



Ubuntu installer default for install is to put grub boot loader in first drive. If UEFI, then both share the ESP - efi system partition on first drive. If old BIOS, grub overwrites the Windows boot loader on first drive. Most with multiple drives prefer to have ESP on Ubuntu drive, so if first drive fails they still can boot. But Ubiquity installer only installs to first drive. New versions use Subiquity installer & some flavors use Calamares installer which give you choices.

Then what should I do to also have a boot loader on the second drive to boot both windows and ubuntu? Do I need to reinstall ubuntu?
I'll add that when Windows Boot Manager is first in Boot Option Priorities, I don't get the option to choose which system to select at all, and windows starts up right away.

Windows will not boot Ubuntu, although some have posted work arounds. You need an ESP - efi system partition on Ubuntu drive. If drive not huge, you can add it by shrinking some other partition. Normally you make ESP as first partition, FAT32 wtih boot,esp flags. You can then change mount of ESP in fstab to new UUID of new ESP and reinstall grub. Once that works best to remove (backup first) /EFI/ubuntu folder in Windows drive's ESP. Make sure ubuntu entry in UEFI uses ubuntu drive's partUUID. Not really difficult to change, but if new user may be easier to reinstall/repartition first.

Sounds quite complicated for me, so I prefer to reinstall ubuntu system. The question is what should I pay attention to when reinstalling? Can I ask you for step-by-step instructions or a link to one?

I partition in advance with gparted to create gpt, then add ESP & / partitions leaving some space for future use.  I use smaller / & separate data partition(s). Then use Something Else to change/edit partitions. https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview But depending on installer.  Remove esp flag from Windows before install to second or external drive - Tim Richardson
https://askubuntu.com/questions/16988/how-do-i-install-ubuntu-to-a-usb-key-without-using-startup-disk-creator &

The description is lacking some details of your installations, like: where the boot loader is (disk A or B), and what boot loader is used?  What was the order of OS installations that you have carried out (which OS first)?  (EDIT: no picture with an error, no picture with round brackets you are referring to.)
However:
In a nutshell, all systems that you want to have bootable on your computer (using one distinct BIOS setup/setting) shall use the same disk for their boot-loaders.  This way you should expect a boot menu on power-on where you choose the system to continue with.  (Linux may be perceived easier to install its bootloader on another (Windows) disk, than Windows.)
If you installed Windows on one disk, then installed Linux on another disk, separately, you will have to choose in BIOS which disk you want your computer to boot from each time you want to boot the other OS.  Tedious this may seem, it is a possible (but rarely used on bare metal, I think) way to go if the installations have their separate boot loaders on separate disks.

I have edited the attached photo. I bought the laptop with windows 10 installed, so it came first. I honestly don't know what boot loader I am using and where it is located. I installed ubuntu according to the instructions on this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mXyN1aJYefc
I know the instructions are for windows 11, but it works with windows 10 too.

What do you mean by "all systems that you want to have bootable on your computer (using one distinct BIOS setup/setting) shall use the same disk for their boot-loaders"? That is not a requirement at all if that's what you're saying, do you just mean it would be better to have your installations laid out like so? With a single bootloader handling them all?

Anyways @Patryk most likely you're using the same EFI partition Windows is using, hence why the startup disk is the same, both operating systems are found on the same EFI partition; please add the output of sudo fdisk -l to your question so that we can confirm this

I attached a photo of the result of the sudo fdisk -l command. And also I am wondering why in ubuntu I see folders that are on windows, for example "Nowy" with folders , "Clion, Git, Matlab...".

I should add that before installing ubuntu, the partition I used for the installation I separated in windows. I did not leave the space empty, but created a separate partition. When reinstalling, should I not create an empty partition from within windows, but leave the unused memory and only select this unused memory in the ubuntu installation window?
